# How to grow a GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY?

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I have created 2d texture array like this

```
glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,
             0,                // No mipmaps
             GL_RGBA8,         // Internal format
             width, height, 100, // width,height,layer count
             0,                // border?
             GL_RGBA,         // format
             GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, // type
             0);               // pointer to data
```

How do I increase its size from 100 to 200 for example? I guess I would have to create a new 2d array with size 200 and copy the images with `glCopyTexSubImage3D` over?

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, texture_id);
glCopyTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,
                         0,
                         0, 0, 0,
                         0, 0,
                         width, height
                         );
glDeleteTextures(1, &texture_id);

GLuint new_tex_id;
glGenTextures(1, &new_tex_id);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, new_tex_id);

glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,
             0,                
             GL_RGBA8,         
             width, height, 200, 
             0,                
             GL_RGBA,         
             GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
             0);               

//How do I get the data in `GL_READ_BUFFER` into my newly bound texture? 

texture_id = new_tex_id;
```

But how do I actually get the data out of the `GL_READ_BUFFER`?

Comment: That code does not make sense.  `glCopyTexSubImage3D` copies a 2D rectangle of the color buffer into some layer of a 3D texture or 2D array. Your code currently tries to overwrite the first layer in `tex_id` with some current content of the framebuffer, and then deletes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `glCopyImageSubData()` function that @NicolBolas pointed out is the easiest solution if you're ok with requiring OpenGL 4.3 or later.

You can use `glCopyTexSubImage3D()` for this purpose. But since the source for this function is the current read framebuffer, you need to bind your original texture as a framebuffer attachment. The code could roughly look like this:

```
GLuint fbo = 0;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, new_tex_id);

for (int layer = 0; layer < 100; ++layer) {
    glFramebufferTextureLayer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER,
        GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, tex_id, 0, layer);
    glCopyTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,
        0, 0, 0, layer, 0, 0, width, height);
}
```

You can also use `glBlitFramebuffer()` instead:

```
GLuint fbos[2] = {0, 0};
glGenFramebuffers(2, fbos);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, fbos[0]);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, fbos[1]);

for (int layer = 0; layer < 100; ++layer) {
    glFramebufferTextureLayer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER,
        GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, tex_id, 0, layer);
    glFramebufferTextureLayer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER,
        GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, new_tex_id, 0, layer);
    glBlitFramebuffer(
        0, 0, width, height, 0, 0, width, height,
        GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST);
}
```

The two options should be more or less equivalent. I would probably go with `glBlitFramebuffer()` since it's a newer function (introduced in 3.0), and it might be much more commonly used. So it might be more optimized. But if this is performance critical in your application, you should try both, and compare.

Answer (score 2):

`glCopyTexSubImage` copies data *from the framebuffer*, not from a texture. That's why it doesn't take two texture objects to copy with.

Copying from a texture into another texture requires [`glCopyImageSubData`](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glCopyImageSubData). This is an OpenGL 4.3 function, from ARB_copy_image. A similar function can also be found in NV_copy_image, which may be more widely supported.

BTW, you should generally avoid doing this operation at all. If you needed a 200 element array texture, you should have allocated that the first time.